# Code Signing in iOS 10 Resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed

Tags: ios, xcode8, code-signing

CodeSign /Users/amb00060/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AbbottVascular-cfevyugyfkhswodgsynlfuvfsxyo/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/GFIM.app
    cd "/Volumes/DATA/New Data/DESKTOP/Ongoing Projects/GFIM_1.9.4/DeliveredCode_May2 2/abbottvascular"
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

Signing Identity:     "-"

```
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign - --timestamp=none /Users/amb00060/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AbbottVascular-cfevyugyfkhswodgsynlfuvfsxyo/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/GFIM.app
```

/Users/amb00060/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AbbottVascular-cfevyugyfkhswodgsynlfuvfsxyo/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/GFIM.app: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

What is my problem here because I am using a enterprise distribution provisioning profile. I have only one single certificate in my keychain. My other versions of the same project is running in Xcode but this latest one is not running. Please help me, am breaking my head.

Thanks always.

I have tried with Guru solutions but nothing is working though for me. Tried most of all the solutions. Still asking that

Signing Identity: "-"

This is very uncommon just only a dash. What is the mistake happening pls elaborate a little for me who understand this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't your certificates, etc. it's your data. Do you have pdfs or other files you include in your app?  Google for "Xcode detritus" (no quotes) and you should find plenty of hits. There's even a free app in the App Store that will remove it for you.

Comment: No I am not using any PDF, there are so many ways but not working for me.

Comment: Guru and Brad have pointed you in the proper direction

Comment: I have tried everything but its not working

Comment: Did you try the app? It works for me. I have to use it occasionally because I sometimes include documents in my apps. I could be wrong but I think other files can cause this problem as well. Run the app, point to your build folder. It will clean it if detritus. Hit compile and it should work as long as you don't copy new polluted files to the build file. In that case run the cleaner app in your source (copy source) folder as well. Let me know if I'm not clear.

Comment: It worked like a charm..... Thank u so much for insisting me to do this. I was so frustrated with all other solutions but the guy who made the app is a saviour.

Comment: I agree! Glad you solved your issue.