# "resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed" error when deploying a Xamarin.Forms app to a physical iOS device

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, macos-high-sierra

When deploying a Xamarin.Forms app to a physical iOS device running iOS 12.1.4, I encounter this error:
resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed

Thus the app cannot be deployed onto the device.

Answer (score 6):

Although this question already has answers at

- [resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed Xcode 8 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40278101/resource-fork-finder-information-or-similar-detritus-not-allowed-xcode-8-error)
- [Code Signing in iOS 10 Resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44652288/code-signing-in-ios-10-resource-fork-finder-information-or-similar-detritus-no)
- [Code Sign Error in macOS High Sierra Xcode - resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652867/code-sign-error-in-macos-high-sierra-xcode-resource-fork-finder-information)
- [Code Signing error in XCode 8.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43105334/code-signing-error-in-xcode-8-2-1)

I'd like to add in the specific steps for Visual Studio 2019 (Preview) that have worked for me consistently on Mac OS:

1. Delete all the `bin` and `obj` folders (from all your projects, e.g. from the common folder, and from each platform-specific folder).
2. Close the solution and open it again (so that the packages get restored).
3. Do a Build -> Rebuild All. You don't need to connect the physical device to your computer yet.
4. In the Solution Explorer, go to the iOS project root folder (right-click on the iOS project in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer, then select Tools -> Open in Terminal) and execute `find . | xargs -0 xattr -c`.
5. Connect the iOS device to your computer and run the build so that it gets installed on the device.

Comment: Update for .NET MAUI: in step 4, instead of executing find . | xargs -0 xattr -c, just go to project root directory and run this command: xattr -cr .

Answer (score 1):

Check if any image or resource files without extension. One of the possible cause is, in any of the iOS project in the visual studio have image resources without extension (Ex: sample instead of sample.png)

After correcting the file extension, clean and build.