# Xamarin 'resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed' error when debugging on physcial iPhone but not simulator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am getting these two errors when trying to deploy and debug a Xamarin iOS app on a physical iPhone 12 mini attached via USB to a Macbook Pro M3 running Visual Stuido 2022 for Mac.

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(3,3): Error: /usr/bin/codesign exited with code 1:
/Users/joshbula/Documents/Xamarin/FMEAMobile4/FMEAMobile4/FMEAMobile4.iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone13.1-17.1.2/FMEAMobile4.iOS.app: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed (FMEAMobile4.iOS)

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(3,3): Error: Failed to codesign '/Users/joshbula/Documents/Xamarin/FMEAMobile4/FMEAMobile4/FMEAMobile4.iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone13.1-17.1.2/FMEAMobile4.iOS.app': /Users/joshbula/Documents/Xamarin/FMEAMobile4/FMEAMobile4/FMEAMobile4.iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone13.1-17.1.2/FMEAMobile4.iOS.app: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed         (FMEAMobile4.iOS)

I have already tried all of the suggestions [in this post from 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55320965/resource-fork-finder-information-or-similar-detritus-not-allowed-error-when), so I think it is a different issue due to another possible recent Apple change, but I don't know.  Running the xattr -cr command on the folder, and the cleanDetritus app from the App Store, followed by clearing the bin and obj folders and a clean and rebuild has not worked.

It's running Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2244. It builds and runs fine on all the simulators, but not the physical device.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, let me know if I should include any other details. Thanks!

Comment: The error message you occurred is usually caused by the image or audio resources in the project containing resource forks or Finder info. You can try to replace or temporarily remove the image or audio resources in the project and then deploy the project to the iPhone to determine whether the problem is the one mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you, yes, I thought that running the "xattr -cr <path_to_project_dir>" command would clean all those up so I didn't think much more about this as a possible solution. It turns out that it might be something with iCloud adding that extra Finder info... My source was in my "Documents" folder, which syncs to iCloud, and when I copied the whole project to a different folder on the drive and ran it from there, everything worked fine.